# GET request when using GitHub pages seems outdated

Tags: github-pages

I am doing the following request on a repo in my github pages (https://github.com/equalcoding/equalcoding.github.io - `/js/main.js`)

```
let ele = document.getElementById('blog');
let request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', `https://dev.to/api/articles?username=${devtoUsername}&state=${state}&per_page=${perPage}&page=${page}&time=${new Date()}`, true)
request.onload = function () {
    response = JSON.parse(request.response);
    response.forEach(response => populateBlogDOM(response, ele));
}
request.send();
```

Yesterday I created a record in the API provider and it gave me a single result which was correct, however, today I created another record and it still returns the same record it did yesterday. However, when I test this locally it works fine and I get both records.

Below is side by side comparison of the two requests. Same parameters just the environment is different. This makes me wonder if it is something GitHub does. If so how do I disable this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it should be `time=${+new Date()}`

Comment: @AllanChain in the only reason why I added that `time` parameter to create a dynamic query, I was thinking it is being cached because it is always the same query. But alas that was not the case.

Comment: i.e., I get the same result regardless of what the query is.